# C++ and Oracle instant client connection on intel Mac

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm having trouble establishing a connection to the oracle instant client in a c++ program on my 2019 intel mac. I have the basic and sdk packages installed and have included the right path in coderunner on vsCode but every time i try to run my code I get this error. I've followed the exact instructions in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coAN6vaGC3U

Here is what happens when I try to run the code:

```
dyld[24679]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.19.1
  Referenced from: <686BC664-A63D-3B48-BAE6-32C58733E866> /Users/gabrielmebratu/Dbs311project/DBS311NGG_ASS2_group11
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib.19.1' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib.19.1' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      "/Users/gabrielmebratu/Dbs311project/"DBS311NGG_ASS2_group11
```

The library exists in the folder despite the error. The problem isn't my code as well because i've been testing the connection using this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "it works\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to fix?

I've tried storing the packages in a different path on my computer but I still have the same result.

Comment: Is this an Intel mac?  If not, start by making sure you are compiling an x86_64 binary so that Rosetta will work.  Update your question with this info and also share how you are linking the program.